# Exe to service possible?

Tags: windows, service, exe

Is it possible to have a .exe run as a windows service?

Comment: probably belongs on super user: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

Comment: Do you have the source of the .exe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Windows app called SC.exe : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

Answer (score 0):

yes.

cygrunsrv (cygwin) http://web.mit.edu/cygwin/cygwin_v1.3.2/usr/doc/Cygwin/cygrunsrv.README
or 
INSTSRV/SRVANY (microsoft) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

Answer (score 0):

This works great in Windows:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/xyntservice.aspx

JR

Answer (score 0):

A paid app, [Application as service](http://www.eltima.com/products/application-as-service/) does this as well. It has a GUI for adding, removing and configuring services that makes things easy.

If you're comfortable with Cygwin though, it's free and I've used that to good effect also.

Answer (score 0):

This as well: [RunAsService](http://sourceforge.net/projects/runasservice/)

Answer (score -1):

Nope. It must inherit from ServiceBase and be installed to the OS as a service... The os basically is the process/context your code runs in.

Comment: What? No. Another service could easily host something "as a service" for you. This is what srvany does. Also "the OS basically is the process/context your code runs in" doesn't begin to make sense and sounds like a terrible oversimplification of how operating systems work.

And ServiceBase is a .NET class, you can write native services, too.